# laravel перенос фабрик в подмодуль

Tags: php, laravel, composer, git-submodule

Как перенести фабрики из database\factories в submodule\factories, чтобы laravel их видел? Пробовал просто перетащить папку и в composer изменить

```
"classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "database/factories"
    ]
```

на

```
"classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "submodule/factories"
    ]
```

но фреймворк их не видит.
Делал composer dump-autoload -o
Пробовал прописать в сервис провайдере
Как правильно выполнить перенос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путь до папки `APP_ROOT/database/ влияет не только на поиск фабрик, но и на сидеры и миграции.

Путь до папки задан в коде класса `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` и через конфигурационные файлы его не переопределить на другое значение.

Но это можно сделать через реализацию своего сервис-провайдера, например так:

1. В папку `APP_ROOT/app/Providers/` положите файл `DbPathServiceProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DbPathServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        app()->useDatabasePath("submodule");
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //

    }
}
```

2. Подключите созданный сервис-провайдер в файле `APP_ROOT/config/app.php`:

```
...
'providers' => [
    ....
    App\Providers\DbPathServiceProvider::class
],
...
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! 
Видел похожие ответы, но там через костыли подключали сервис провайдеры!!